# Computer only has 32 bits of memory addresses, but has 16GB of ram installed and working?

Tags: c++, windows

I just started learning C++ and was surprised to see that when calling &varname, I got a 8 hex-digit-long number.
Assuming this math is correct:

2^(8 hexits x 4 bits hexit^-1) x 1 bytes address^-1 = 4.29497e+09 bytes of RAM addressable

I should only be able to address 4GB of ram, and yet my computer has 16GB, all of which work. Does this mean my computer actually has 32 bits of storage per memory address?

Comment: Your program is running in 32 bit mode, you operating system is running in 64 bit mode.

Comment: What does that have to do with c++ specifically?

Comment: 32-bit executables can only access 4GB, but if the OS is 64-bit then multiple processes can each use 4GB.  A 64-bit program can access more than 4GB but will only run on a 64-bit OS.  This is why lots of software comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Comment: `when calling &varname, I got a 8 hex-digit-long number` What exactly did you call? Please post the code. Note that `1` has as many bits as `0x0000000001`.

Comment: with 32 bits you get 4 GB if you're lucky. One major OS I can think of capped you at 2 GB, probably because of all the fools using `int`s for pointers and vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibility 1: Your program is compiled for 32 bit and your OS is 64 bit.

Possibility 2: Your program is compiled for 32 bit and your OS is 32 bit with AWE support and can actually map all 16 GB, just not to all processes. EDIT: Now knowing the OS is Windows, the only Windows version ever released that can actually do this is Windows Server 2003 x86 Datacenter Edition.

Possibility 3: Your program is compiled for 32 bit and your OS is 32 bit and only using the bottom 4GB.

The common denominator is your program is compiled for 32 bit.

However there is a possibility 4: whatever method you used to output the pointer dropped leading zeros. It's unnatural but it's possible to have written it like that.

Comment: Possibility 1 was my situation. In visual studio I selected x86, rather than x64, thinking this meant like the x86 instruction set, not 32 bit mode. (I will accept this answer in 7 minutes).